# How to append a new sheet to existing Excel workbook?

Tags: r

I have exported my dataframe into 3 different Excel workbooks based on their "Country" and I have another dataframe that have the same exact countries and I would like them to be exported to the current existing workbook in which I have created.

```
#Create Dataframe
df = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 15, 60, 23, 25, 60, 50, 18, 31))

df2 = data.frame(Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c("James", "Gordon", "Jackson", "Harrison", "Reid", "Ashen", "Lewis", "Maokai", "Federick"))

#Split dataframe according to their Countries
splitdf = split(df, df$Country)

#Write workbook
save_data <- function(df, name) {
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, name)
  writeDataTable(wb, name, df, tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(name, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
}

#Print workbook
mapply(
  save_data,
  splitdf,
  names(splitdf)
)
```

Is there a way for me to append df2 to a new sheet based on it's unique Countries to the existing Workbooks that I have created without overwriting the original file?

Comment: Do you mean, adding an additional sheet to each workbook with data coming from countries in `df2`?

Comment: @Duck yes, I would like to add an additional sheet to each workbook with data from df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(openxlsx)
#Create lists
L1 <- split(df,df$Country)
L2 <- split(df2,df2$Country)
#Write workbook
save_data <- function(x,y, name) {
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, name)
  writeDataTable(wb, name,x , tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")
  addWorksheet(wb, paste0(name,'.df2'))
  writeDataTable(wb, paste0(name,'.df2'), y,
                 tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(name, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
}
#Print workbook
mapply(
  save_data,
  x=L1,y=L2,name=names(L1)
)
```

Some outputs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed! Cheers

Comment: @realbeast91 Always glad to help :)